# Reverse engineering the objective function

Tags: algorithms, optimization

If there is a finite iteration algorithm can we find a function that this algorithm optimizes, in hindsight?

Edit:

Suppose there is a set of functions $f_i(x)$, where $x\in \mathbb R^n$, $i=\{1,\dots,N\}$ and the algorithm works on these function. Can we find a $g(f_1,\dots,f_N)$ up to a constant, such that the algorithm was the optimal solution method for $g()$?

Answer (score 0):

No, because for every objective function $f(x)$ you can find infinitely many other functions that have the exact same maxima, e.g., $g(x)=f(x)+1$.

Comment: Thanks. But I wouldn't mind a constant difference for sure

Comment: There are also other functions with the same minimum/maximum where the difference is not constant, for example $g(x)=log(f(x))$. Any positive monotone transformation retains minima/maxima. Without more information reverse-engineering just isn't possible.